# Round Floats within an expression

Tags: sympy

I ran into the following problem:

I have a sympy matrix of sympy expressions, each cell looking something like the following example, call it `ex1`:

```
In: ex1

Out: -mu_0_0 + t*((0.8*mu_0_1 + 2.22044604925031e-16)*Max(0, alpha_0_1_4)**2 + (0.8*mu_1_1 + 2.22044604925031e-16)*Max(0, alpha_0_1_3)**2 + (0.8*mu_3_1 + 2.22044604925031e-16)*Max(0, alpha_0_1_2)**2 + (0.8*mu_6_1 + 2.22044604925031e-16)*Max(0, alpha_0_1_1)**2 + (0.4*mu_10_0 + 0.4*mu_10_1 - 0.4)*Max(0, alpha_0_1_0)**2) + (-t + 1)*(0.498558013279766*mu_0_1 + 0.0238962672572783*mu_10_0 + 0.0238962672572783*mu_10_1 + 0.18596764210715*mu_1_1 + 0.0201673973158616*mu_3_1 + 0.0475144127826656*mu_6_1 - 0.023896267257278) + Max(0, -alpha_0_0_0)**2
```

The matrix is later to be lambdified. However, before that, I would like to get rid of the `2.22044604925031e-16` and like floats; these are artifcats from some other part of the code and should be 0.

I would like to clean the expressions in my matrix cells from these, but can't figure out how to.

`ex1.round()` crashes my python when applied to `ex1`, and it does not seem to work for simple expression such as

```
In: sympy.sympify(0.01*t).round(1)  
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

If I try it via N, as

```
In: sympy.N(eq, n=3)
```

I get:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

(I am not even sure this would work anyway, as I understand this would just reduce the floats to n significant digits?)

Is there any way to clean these expressions in the way I want?

Thanks in advance!

I will leave the expression structure, in case it is of any help:

```
sympy.srepr(ex1)  

"Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('mu_0_0')), Mul(Symbol('t'), Add(Mul(Add(Mul(Float('0.80000000000000004', prec=15), Symbol('mu_0_1')), Float('2.2204460492503131e-16', prec=15)), Pow(Max(Integer(0), Symbol('alpha_0_1_4')), Integer(2))), Mul(Add(Mul(Float('0.80000000000000004', prec=15), Symbol('mu_1_1')), Float('2.2204460492503131e-16', prec=15)), Pow(Max(Integer(0), Symbol('alpha_0_1_3')), Integer(2))), Mul(Add(Mul(Float('0.80000000000000004', prec=15), Symbol('mu_3_1')), Float('2.2204460492503131e-16', prec=15)), Pow(Max(Integer(0), Symbol('alpha_0_1_2')), Integer(2))), Mul(Add(Mul(Float('0.80000000000000004', prec=15), Symbol('mu_6_1')), Float('2.2204460492503131e-16', prec=15)), Pow(Max(Integer(0), Symbol('alpha_0_1_1')), Integer(2))), Mul(Add(Mul(Float('0.40000000000000002', prec=15), Symbol('mu_10_0')), Mul(Float('0.40000000000000002', prec=15), Symbol('mu_10_1')), Float('-0.3999999999999998', prec=15)), Pow(Max(Integer(0), Symbol('alpha_0_1_0')), Integer(2))))), Mul(Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t')), Integer(1)), Add(Mul(Float('0.49855801327976634', prec=15), Symbol('mu_0_1')), Mul(Float('0.02389626725727826', prec=15), Symbol('mu_10_0')), Mul(Float('0.02389626725727826', prec=15), Symbol('mu_10_1')), Mul(Float('0.18596764210714989', prec=15), Symbol('mu_1_1')), Mul(Float('0.020167397315861646', prec=15), Symbol('mu_3_1')), Mul(Float('0.047514412782665633', prec=15), Symbol('mu_6_1')), Float('-0.023896267257278034', prec=15))), Pow(Max(Integer(0), Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('alpha_0_0_0'))), Integer(2)))"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One can traverse the expression tree with `preorder_traversal`, and replace floats by their rounded values. In the example below, the floats are rounded to 1 digit after the decimal dot.

```
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x y')
ex1 = 3.1415*(2.00003*x + 3e-12) + x*(y + 0.0003*x - 4e-13)**2 + 1.234567
ex2 = ex1
for a in preorder_traversal(ex1):
    if isinstance(a, Float):
        ex2 = ex2.subs(a, round(a, 1))
print(ex1)  # original
print(ex2)  # rounded
```

Output (with original expression for comparison):

```
x*(0.0003*x + y - 4.0e-13)**2 + 6.283094245*x + 1.23456700000942
x*y**2 + 6.3*x + 1.2
```

Comment: Works like a charm, and also allows me great flexibility in what I can check for/replace with -- thanks a bunch!